# Rich Text Editor - Cursor Stays in the latest added div

Tags: javascript, jquery, rich-text-editor

I am trying to implement a simple RTE, i have come far as allowing the user to add elements. But when i add the first div i cant seem to click on a region where i can add another div to the location i want.

Every element has contenteditable set to true so why cant i select the placeholders i click on?

Im also using an IFRAME to allow the RTE to work.

### HTML STRUCTURE

```
 <div class="content" contenteditable="true">
       <div class="menuitem" contenteditable="true">
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: In my experience it's really not worth your while coding your own RTE, when there are some many free ones out there, ranging from heavy to extremely light-weight

Comment: @roryok, i see your point mate, but its something that i have wanted to look into. Becuase where i work we have implemented TinyMCE but for more customization i have been asked to take up this project